# Receive data in service emitted from another service

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a service (printService) from a controller, From this service calling another one service (dataService) where I have emit method.

Now I need to receive the data in printService emitted from dataService. I am new to AngularJS, Please help me.

Comment: Can you share the some code of the services? `app.factory [params]`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping a emit method, you can return the data from your method in dataService.
If you can't return data, then listen for that emit event in `printService`

```
$rootScope.$on(<your emit method name>, function({
   //do your stuff here
})
```

Remember to emit event on `rootScope`.

Comment: Do  I need to add any variable in scope to receive the result from emit method?

Comment: you don't need to put a variable. You need to keep a listener. The function above will be called whenever you emit the event.